# Importing another module from another subdirectory of the current directory's parent directory (python)

Tags: python, import, module, path

I'm attempting to write a game. I therefore have lots of different types of code and want to arrange them in a useful hierarchy.

I've looked at solutions that involve placing `__init__.py` in each folder but I'm still somewhat confused, though not as much as the python interpreter.

Now suppose `resource1.py` wants to import a function from `physics1.py`, or indeed any other `.py` file in the `Game` directory, how would I go about doing so?

I've tried `from bin.physics.physics1 import function` but obviously that doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

```
/Game
    launcher.py
    /bin
        game.py
        __init__.py
        /physics
            __init__.py
            physics1.py
            physics2.py
    /resources
        __init__.py
        resource1.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with the normal import mechanism unless you make `Game` a package (i.e., by putting an `__init__.py` inside the `Game` directory).  The python relative import system only works *within packages*.  It is not a general system for referring to arbitrary modules by their location in the directory structure.  If you make Game a package, then you could do `from ..bin.physics.physics1 import function`.

Edit: Note also that relative imports don't work from a script executed as the main program.  If you try to run `resource.py` directly and it uses relative imports, you'll get a "relative import attempted in non-package" error.  It will work if you import resource from another module.  This is because the relative import system is based on the "name" of the executing module, and when you run a script directly its name is `__main__` instead of whatever it would usually be named.  It's possible to get around this using [the `__package__` keyword](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) if you really need to, but it can be a bit tricky.

Comment: I've put the `__init__.py` file in `Game` and I still get `ImportError: No module named physics.physics1`.

Comment: I just tested it with that directory structure and it works fine.  Are you sure the directory structure is as you said and you have `__init__.py` in every directory?

Comment: Oh dear, I forgot to put an `__init__.py` in the last directory. So it now works from `launcher.py` but from `resource1.py` I get `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.

Comment: See my edited response.  Relative imports don't work from within a file that you execute directly; they only work from within imported modules.  If you import resource from somewhere else, it should work.