# Importing a class from a different directory

Tags: python, import, module, hierarchy

I am new to python and I am trying to create my module hierarchy:

```
projectDir:
  __init__.py

directory1:
   __init__.py
   file1.py
   file2.py

directory2:
   __init__.py
   file1.py
   file2.py

directory3:
   __init__.py
   file1.py
   file2.py
```

I want to be able to import a class that is in directory1 file1.py e.g. when I am in file1.py in directory2. I want to do this without modifying the sys.path or import source code using imp.

I created `__init__.py` files in all directories and I used relative importing to import the module from directory1.
But then I need to run the script in directory2 directly which it fails for the reason explained here: 
[Relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335830/importing-another-module-from-another-subdirectory-of-the-current-directorys-pa?rq=1)

How can I avoid this error with efficient code?

Comment: why dont you want to use imp?

Comment: because I expect to find a better solution, since the project code base is large and there will be a lot of importing between the modules.

Comment: oh i see well i dont know of any other ways than that and `sys.path.append`

Comment: The layout looks like there shouldn't be cross-references between the submodules. Can you design your library so that you only glue the pieces together in some higher-level module? That would avoid the cross-imports

Comment: one of the dirs is a configuration dir and most the other modules will have to import from there...